# Flutter : By default, Android Pie will request that apps use HTTPS no HTTP request

Tags: http, networking, https, flutter, android-9.0-pie

By default, Android Pie will request that apps use HTTPS connections instead of HTTP. 
So unable to hit restful API in HTTP

Answer (score 2):

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/04/protecting-users-with-tls-by-default-in.html?m=1 explains how to opt out for a specific domain or arbitrary domains

> ```
> <network-security-config>
>     <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
>         <domain includeSubdomains="true">insecure.example.com</domain>
>         <domain includeSubdomains="true">insecure.cdn.example.com</domain>
>     </domain-config>
> </network-security-config>
> ```

I'm not sure the limitation introducted in Android Pie and the opt-out mentioned here apply to HTTP connections made using `dart:io`.

Comment: I was aware with this in case of native android development but now i have implemented the same in case of Flutter app
Thank you bro...

Comment: does this works for you ? I have added and it doesn't affect